# CollapsingToolbarLayout Title not showing when using customize toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to make custom tooolbar and show a text in CollapsingToolbarLayout. when i use below code, just my title show correct!

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="@drawable/img_back"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/app_orange_color"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="-40dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

but when i customize toolbar like below code, title of collapsing toolbar will be hidden:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="@drawable/img_back"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/app_orange_color"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="-40dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_toolbar"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:gravity="left">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgCard"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_local_grocery_store_white_24dp" />

                    <com.example.shop.widgets.CustomBoldTextview
                        android:id="@+id/txtCardBadge"
                        android:layout_width="19dp"
                        android:layout_height="19dp"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imgCard"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgCard"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/drawable_circle_card_badge"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="@color/app_white_color"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

what i need is to show both my custom toolbar and show title in middle of collapsing toolbar.
what should i do?